# How do I specify to prawn to truncate table cell content?

Tags: ruby, pdf-generation, prawn

I'd like to instruct Prawn to truncate the contents of table cells instead of wrapping them.

I've tried setting the style as follows, but it has no effect:

```
options = {
  cell_style: {
    overflow: :truncate
  },
}
pdf.table(entries, options)
```

If there is no direct way to specify truncation, I need a workaround recipe.

Please consider the following:

- I cannot truncate the strings themselves, because the font is not fixed-width
- calculating the width of each string is acceptable, but I would also need a way to retrieve the column width.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A fixed height could be used, but only if the height of the text is fixed. Only the first line of the text will be printed.

Example:

```
pdf.table(entries, :cell_style => {:height => 25})
```

Another option is to use a custom wrapper. Details are here:

https://github.com/prawnpdf/prawn/blob/master/lib/prawn/text/formatted/box.rb#L149

Example:

```
module MyWrap
  def wrap(array)
    initialize_wrap(array)
    @line_wrap.wrap_line(:document => @document,
                                  :kerning => @kerning,
                                  :width => available_width,
                                  :arranger => @arranger)
    if enough_height_for_this_line?
      move_baseline_down
      print_line
    end
    @text = @printed_lines.join("\n")
    @everything_printed = @arranger.finished?
    @arranger.unconsumed
  end
end

Prawn::Text::Formatted::Box.extensions << MyWrap

entries = [ ["very long text here", "another very long text here"] ]

Prawn::Document.generate("test.pdf") do
  table entries, :cell_style => { :inline_format => true }
end
```

I just copy the original [`wrap`](https://github.com/prawnpdf/prawn/blob/master/lib/prawn/core/text/formatted/wrap.rb) method and remove the `while` loop in order to print only the first line of the text.

Note that `:inline_format => true` must be used in order to get  `Prawn::Text::Formatted::Box` working.

Answer (score 0):

http://prawn.majesticseacreature.com/docs/0.11.1/Prawn/Text/Formatted.html

That has a way to truncate text in a box with

```
formatted_text_box(array, options={})
```

But it's not a table. I don't think there is any way to do it with a table, you'll have to use textboxes.